# What is the technical term for Bass 'growl' or 'roar'?

Tags: technique, terminology, bass-guitar, electric-bass-guitar

I've been looking everywhere for the past 2 days for the terms of these two awesome electric bass techniques and couldn't find 'em.

I want to know their technical *or* common names..

1. When you slide your finger up then down fast, and make a [roaring, 'growling' sound](http://ivcdn.net/growl.mp3).
2. I don't exactly know what is done but it creates a [boom-like sound](http://ivcdn.net/boom1.mp3). [Another Example](http://ivcdn.net/boom2.mp3).

Comment: side note - check out these Cliff Burton songs:  The Call of Ktulu, Anesthesia, Seek and Destroy.  They have some great examples of making a bass scream like a bloody tiger

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The technical term is glissando or gliss slide. Whether you're going up or down or both, basically it's a long slide.